# Powershell For-Loop throws MissingVariableNameAfterForeach

Tags: powershell, cmd, foreach, zabbix

Why do I get the error "MissingVariableNameAfterForeach" for the following:

`powershell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "foreach($file in Get-ChildItem C:){((Get-Date)-$file.LastWriteTime).ToString('dd')}"`

The command is supposed to print out the day since today of the last file/folder write in C:\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the help text:

```
PS C:\> powershell.exe /?
```

> ```
> If the value of Command is a script block, the script block must be enclosed
> in braces ({}). You can specify a script block only when running PowerShell.exe
> in Windows PowerShell.
> ```

Try this:

```
powershell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command {Get-ChildItem C: | ForEach-Object{($_.LastWriteTime).ToString('dd')}}
```

Comment: Hey thanks, it works this way. Still a problem though: when I run the command from Zabbix Server it does not work. I don't know why. But since this was not my question, your answer is perfectly correct and works. Thank you.

Comment: See the help text above "You can specify a script block only when running PowerShell.exe in Windows PowerShell." - probably why Zabbix won't work? No idea about how Zabbix works but maybe running a scriptfile instead is a better option than running a command block?

Answer (score 2):

Your command will work if you enclose the Get-ChildItem in parentheses.

```
powershell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command ^
    "foreach($file in (Get-ChildItem C:)){((Get-Date)-$file.LastWriteTime).ToString('dd')}"
```

Comment: Hmm, true. Both answers work. And I tried the lit's with zabbix. Doesn't work there, but locally it works as it should.

Comment: Is the error message still the same when it is run in Zabbix?

Comment: It may be PowerShell version related, @lit, _I vaguely recall that `ToString`, used like that, outputs an error in early versions_.

Comment: Yes could be, but consider it works locally in the same powershell, on the same server ...

Answer (score 1):

I may have understood your question, because the existing answers do not seem to provide the information I thought you were looking for.

Whilst these examples don't specifically answer the question posed in your title, they are intended to output what I think you were looking for.

Here therefore is my [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) attempt:

```bat
@"%__AppDir__%WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoProfile -Command^
 "Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\'|Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime|"^
 "Select-Object -Last 1|Format-Table -AutoSize -Property Name,"^
 "@{Name='DaysOld';Expression={[Int]$((Get-Date)-$_.LastWriteTime).TotalDays}}"
@Pause
```

And obviously the [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd) version, to be on topic:

```bat
"%__AppDir__%WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoProfile -Command "Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\'|Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime|Select-Object -Last 1|Format-Table -AutoSize -Property Name,@{Name='DaysOld';Expression={[Int]$((Get-Date)-$_.LastWriteTime).TotalDays}}"
```

---

Just in case it is simply my misunderstanding, perhaps this [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) may work for you:

```bat
@"%__AppDir__%WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoProfile -Command^
 "Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\'|Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime -Descending|"^
 "Format-Table -AutoSize -Property Name,"^
 "@{Name='DayInMonth';Expression={($_.LastWriteTime).ToString('dd')}},"^
 "@{Name='DaysOld';Expression={[Int]$((Get-Date)-$_.LastWriteTime).TotalDays}}"
@Pause
```

[cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd) version:

```bat
"%__AppDir__%WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoProfile -Command "Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\'|Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime -Descending|Format-Table -AutoSize -Property Name,@{Name='DayInMonth';Expression={($_.LastWriteTime).ToString('dd')}},@{Name='DaysOld';Expression={[Int]$((Get-Date)-$_.LastWriteTime).TotalDays}}"
```

---

In both cases, you'll note because I'm not running a PowerShell script, there is no need to stipulate an execution policy. Commands should work as if being run directly in the PowerShell window.

Comment: Hey there, I tried both your examples. Unfortunately both do not work. I get the error "UnexpectedToken for "-Command". It probably has something to do with the quotes. Even if I remove them it throws errors for the Subtraction ... it says no overloading for op_Subtraction found.

For your information, I run the command on a MS Win Server 2012 R2 Server.
And yes you are right with the Execution Policy. Thank you

Comment: @user3166101, are they failing in Zabbix only, because I can assure you that it is based on my standard template. It is tested and working in even in Powershell 2.0, and all versions up to, but not including 7.0, _(I have no interest in previews and release candidates, so until it reaches general availability, I'll not be testing Powershell 7.0)_. I did not provide the answer with doublequotes, and expect you to remove them, in fact all answers posted should be tested as written first, (adjusting only the `-Path` as necessary, _I doubt you're really checking the root of the system drive_).

Comment: @user3166101, have you tried to adjust the default 3 seconds that the Zabbix agent waits for a response? just to see if it is taking slightly longer, and therefore causing your issues. Can you please test the command(s) in cmd.exe, without Zabbix, and you could also test the batch-file version, in both environments, and provide feedback. Additionally, there's nothing to stop you from testing the offered solutions as Powershell scripts, obviously with the execution policy put back in. As I see it, the code is fine, your issue is with Zabbix. It is technically a software issue, not programming.

Comment: Okay I did test the cmd/batch version. CMD Version is working from shell. And as I can see it provides a nicer formatting than my thingy. The batch version did not work though (with -NoProfile and -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ....) for both versions.
Zabbix is still not working. I will now try to run it as script from Zabbix. 
For anybody using Zabbix, this link might help: https://www.zabbix.com/forum/zabbix-troubleshooting-and-problems/41811-user-parameter-and-powershell-variable-problem
I will report later how my results are.

Comment: @user3166101, the `-File` option is when you're running a powershell script, _(.ps1)_, you're only running a powershell command so will not need it, just use the `-Command` option as I had, and enclose that command in doublequotes as I did. I have no idea if Zabbix runs the command exactly as is, or whether it passes it as one or more parameters, but those doublequotes should be left in place to prevent any potential poison characters from affecting things during that pass. Surely you can just run a batch file from Zabbix, e.g. `UserParameter=WHATEVER,FULLPATH\FILENAME.bat`

Comment: okay, as of now it is working. currently i use the following line in the zabbix agent config:
<code>UserParameter=backups.db-zip,powershell.exe -NoProfile -Command "((Get-ChildItem E:\db-zip) | ForEach-Object { if( $_.Name -eq 'db_backup.sql.7z' ) { ((Get-Date)-$_.LastWriteTime).ToString('dd')}else{continue} } )"</code>
Don't ask me why it is working now. I added some spaces and enclosed the Get-ChildItem command. Thank you all